# GDB: Run until specific breakpoint

Tags: c++, c, command-line, gdb, breakpoints

In GDB debugging C++ code: I have 15 breakpoints strategically set, but I don't want any of them to activate until I've hit breakpoint #2. Is there any run-until-breakpoint-*n* command in GDB?

I find myself doing one of two things instead:

1. Delete all other breakpoints so that #2 is all that exists, run, re-add all breakpoints; or
2. Run and repeatedly `continue` past all breaks until I see the first break at #2.

I want something like `run-until 2` that will ignore all other breakpoints except #2, but not delete them. Does this exist? Does anyone else have a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of version 7.0 GDB supports python scripting. I wrote a simple script that will temporary disable all enabled breakpoints except the one with specified number and execute GDB `run` command.

Add the following code to the `.gdbinit` file:

```
python
import gdb

class RunUntilCommand(gdb.Command):
    """Run until breakpoint and temporary disable other ones"""

    def __init__ (self):
        super(RunUntilCommand, self).__init__ ("run-until",
                                               gdb.COMMAND_BREAKPOINTS)

    def invoke(self, bp_num, from_tty):
        try:
            bp_num = int(bp_num)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            print "Enter breakpoint number as argument."
            return

        all_breakpoints = gdb.breakpoints() or []
        breakpoints = [b for b in all_breakpoints
                       if b.is_valid() and b.enabled and b.number != bp_num and
                       b.visible == gdb.BP_BREAKPOINT]

        for b in breakpoints:
            b.enabled = False

        gdb.execute("run")

        for b in breakpoints:
            b.enabled = True

RunUntilCommand()
end
```

Comment: This is great. A `continue-until `version would likely be more useful.

Answer (score 11):

You can `enable` and `disable` breakpoints, and these commands will accept a *range*. Use these commands, with a range, at strategic points during the execution of the program.

I assume that when you mention breakpoint *#2* you're referring to the gdb numbering of breakpoints. Here is a simple example gdb session:

```
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001ddb in main at example.c:34
2   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e00 in main at example.c:39
3   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e15 in main at example.c:40
(gdb) disable 1-3
(gdb) enable 2
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1   breakpoint     keep n   0x00001ddb in main at example.c:34
2   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e00 in main at example.c:39
3   breakpoint     keep n   0x00001e15 in main at example.c:40
(gdb)
```

Now only breakpoint #2 is enabled. Run the program and when execution breaks at #2, re-enable all of your desired breakpoints with a range:

```
(gdb) enable 1-3
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001ddb in main at example.c:34
2   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e00 in main at example.c:39
3   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e15 in main at example.c:40
```

You can also mix breakpoint numbers and ranges:

```
(gdb) disable 1 4 6-7
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1   breakpoint     keep n   0x00001ddb in main at example.c:34
2   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e00 in main at example.c:39
3   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e15 in main at example.c:40
4   breakpoint     keep n   0x00001e4f in main at example.c:43
5   breakpoint     keep y   0x00001e4f in main at example.c:44
6   breakpoint     keep n   0x00001e5e in main at example.c:45
7   breakpoint     keep n   0x00001e5e in main at example.c:46
```

Comment: Thanks pb2q, I didn't know about enabling and disabling.

Comment: I am using gdb with Qt Creator. Are the breakpoint IDs consistent through debugging sessions ? I often end up fixing something in my app, recompiling, debugging again, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly less painful than deleting all the other breakpoints would be to `disable` them. That way you don't have to reenter all the stuff associated with the breakpoint to bring it back, just `enable` it again by number.

Answer (score 2):

With `gdb` breakpoints can be disabled instead of deleted. Then all you have to do is reenable them when needed.